# Vue.js v-for nested in Table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Probably a basic one, but I've been struggling for a while. I'm trying to create a Table component in Vue 2, populated by data using v-for.

I'd like it to be:

**Head1** **Head2** **Head3** **Head4**

   1          2         3         4

   11          22         33         44

My best attempt:

```
  <table class="timeline-table">
  <thead>
    <tr v-for="(row, key, v) in rows">
      <th>{{ key }}</th>
      <th>{{ key }}</th>
      <th>{{ key }}</th>
      <th>{{ key }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody v-for="row in rows">
      <tr>
        <td>{{ row.Head1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.Head2 }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.Head3 }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.Head4 }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

With Data structure as:

```
  rows: [{
    Head1: '1',
    Head2: '2',
    Head3: '3',
    Head4: '4'
  },
  {
    Head1: '11',
    Head2: '22',
    Head3: '33',
    Head4: '44'
  }]
```

Have tried various, such as rows[0], and nesting the v-for into a `r in row`, but no success.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the header, you need `v-for` on `th` instead of `tr`, also you need to loop through keys in one row to create the header instead of loop through rows:

```
<table class="timeline-table" id="my-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th v-for="key in Object.keys(rows[0])">{{ key }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody v-for="row in rows">
    <tr>
      <td v-for="key in Object.keys(row)">{{ row[key] }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

See the [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/wubwayu6/2/).